# jQuery .one only show once

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

We have a modal dialog which activates when the user goes outside the browser body. This is using the .one() code below. Isn't .one supposed to show the modal once? Is it possible to do this only once per user (cookie?) so every time they go back to the page it's not repeated when they go outside the body?

```
jQuery("body").one('mouseleave', function() {
    jQuery("#modal-background").toggleClass("active");
    jQuery("#modal-content").toggleClass("active");
});
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

check the cookie's value inside the function, if the value is not 1, it means that the modal dialog hasn't shown yet and it goes inside the if and shows the modal dialog and set value to 1. Then next time the cookie is 1 and it never goes inside the if, so it never shows the modal dialog.

```
jQuery("body").one('mouseleave', function() {
   if(jQuery.cookie("dialogDisplayed") !==1){
     jQuery("#modal-background").toggleClass("active");
     jQuery("#modal-content").toggleClass("active");
     jQuery.cookie("dialogDisplayed", '1', { expires: 30 });
   }
});
```